# Sitecore turning html attribute asp call into string

Tags: asp.net, layout, sitecore

I am pretty new to sitecore as well as .net and am slowly getting the hang of it.  But I am stumped on this one as it seems to go against what I have read in forums and the sitecore documentation.  I am simply trying to add fields into attributes of an html tag.  For example I have this in the sublayout file.

```
<title><%= Sitecore.Context.Item["Page Title"] %></title>
<meta name="description" content='<%= Sitecore.Context.Item["Description"] %>' />
```

The resulting output on the preview is this.

```
<title>Inputted Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= Sitecore.Context.Item["Description"] %>" />
```

Sitecore seems to be just grabbing it as a string.

Anyone seen this before or see where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The below line was correct syntax but it was a sitecore thing using its internal file explorer. Sitecore would encode the < to create the ascii `&lt;`.

```
<meta name="description" content="<%= Sitecore.Context.Item["Description"] %>"
```

Reason I had to use the file explorer is because the clients IT department wouldn't give me access to the server files.  So finally they did and when I accessed the file directly and saved everything worked.  Thanks all for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if this is really happening as you've described it here, it's an ASP.NET parsing error and nothing to do with Sitecore.

Sanity check #1: Is this really ALL the code?  You don't have a runat="server" attribute on your meta tag?  Because that could certainly cause this sort of problem.

If not, this shouldn't happen... BUT... I find it sometimes more reliable to use this construct:

```
<meta name="description" content=<%="\"" + Sitecore.Context.Item["Description"] + "\""%> />
```

Kind of annoying, but might work here.  Or try single quotes around the tag.  In general, if you've got ANY <% %> tags in your HTML output, there is something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to bind it in C#:

```
HtmlMeta metaKeywords = new HtmlMeta();
metaKeywords.Name = "Description";
metaKeywords.Content = Sitecore.Context.Item["Description"];
Header.Controls.Add(metaKeywords);
```

Comment: +1 - Generally used this approach and it allows me more flexibility and less parsing errors while doing so.